# How to debug in magento 2?

Tags: error, fatal-error, debugging, debug, error-log

I'm new to magento and it's really difficult for me to debug codes if something went wrong. What are the best, free tools that we can use to speedup debugging, track the errors, find the exact point of error or source of error?

The errors shown during the setup:di:compile are not much vivid.

Comment: when running any cli commands, you can add -vvv to get a verbose level of reporting. so `setup:di:compile -vvv` will give you more information about the process as it's happening.